# How to add attributes and methods to an instance of a class

Tags: python, class, design-patterns, theano, class-design

I am writing a class that needs to behave as if it were an instance of another class, but have additional methods and attributes.  I've tried doing different things within `__new__` but to no avail.  As an example, here is a half-written class and the desired behavior:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(self, a):
        value = 100  # instances of A need to behave like integers
        ...          # bind A methods and attributes to value?
        return value

    def __init__(self, a)
        self.a = a

    def something(self):
        return 20 + self.a
```

Here is the desired behavior:

```
a = A(10, 5)
print(a + 10)         # 110
print(a * 2)          # 200
print(a.b)            # 5
print(a.something())  # 25
```

I know that when `__new__` returns an instance of a class different than `A`, then `__init__` and other methods are not bound to `value`.  None of the other methods are either.  Is this sort of thing possible?  Am I thinking about this problem the wrong way?

**EDIT**

Note that this class doesn't return instances of integer, just for the purpose of the example.

The reason why (I think that) I can't just subclass, in this case, `int`, is because I need to construct the class when it is called.  `__init__` doesn't return anything, otherwise, maybe I could do something like:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        ...           # logic constructing `value`
        value = 100   # `value` ends up being an integer
        return value

    def something(self):
        return self.a
```

In case this is relevant, `value` is a theano `TensorVariable`.  I would like to add extra methods and attributes to the instance of `TensorVariable` created for use by other functionality downstream.

Comment: Looks like you need a subclass.

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem, but in your "desired behavior" example, you can create a subclass of `int`.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to bind method to `value` because `value` is an `int` and built-in types lack a `__dict__` so you can't add attributes dynamically.

Comment: hopefully the edit clarifies things?